# SUMIFS issue in R

Tags: r, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, sumifs

I'm fairly new to R and have been trying to solve my problem for hours today and thought it's time to turn this over to an expert.  Here's my problem:

I have a dataframe, acme_one , that looks like this (sample of 10s of thousands of rows):

[image]

I have another dataframe, acme_two, that has distinct values from columns (product_id and tag_id from acme_one) that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is add 1 more column to acme_two, totals, so the end result looks like this:

[image]

To populate the new column, totals, here's the logic of the calculation I've been trying to do:

**SUM** values in **quantity** column from dataframe **acme_one** where:

acme_one$product_id == acme.two$product_id AND acme_one$tag_id == acme_two$tag_id AND acme_one$true_false == 'TRUE' AND acme_one$in_out == 'in'

Can you help me with how to do this in R? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `library(dplyr); left_join(acme_two, acme_one %>% filter(true_false, in_out == "in") %>% count(product_id, tag_id, wt=quantity, name = "totals")` That will show the quantity-weighted number of TRUE/"in" for each product/tag in acme_one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package, you can do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

acme_one_totals <- acme_one %>%
  group_by(product_id, tag_id) %>%
  filter(true_false == TRUE, in_out == 'in') %>%
  summarise(totals = sum(quantity), .groups = 'drop') 

acme_two %>%
  left_join(acme_one_totals)
```